# How to get column names from a SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, python-3.x, pandas, mysql-connector

I need to put data from the SQL query into a Pandas dataframe. Please tell me is it possible to get column names the query results? I found that there is a `keys()` function in sqlalchemy for that but it does not work for me:

```
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="SQLServer",
  user="sqlusr",
  password="usrpasswd",
  database="sqldb"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

Query="SELECT Title, Review, Rate FROM reviews;"
cursor.execute(Query)

df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
df.columns = cursor.keys()
```

> AttributeError: 'CMySQLCursor' object has no attribute 'keys'

Comment: why are you not using ``pd.read_sql_query``? [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

Comment: @sammywemmy is exactly right.  Referencing OP's code to execute
"df=pd.read_sql_query(Query, mydb)" 
will pull in a dataframe with the column names.  The cursor is useful for other stuff like executing stored procedures, but for a straight read, this is the way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that it your are searching for

```py
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=DB_USER, password=DB_USER_PASSWORD, host=DB_HOST, database=DB_NAME)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
query = ("SELECT `name`, `ftp_name`, `created_at`, `status` AS `status_customer` FROM `customers"
         "WHERE `status` = %(status)s")

cursor.execute(query, { 'status': 1 })

# cursor.description will give you a tuple of tuples where [0] for each is the column header.

num_fields = len(cursor.description)
field_names = [i[0] for i in cursor.description]

print(num_fields)

print(field_names)

>>> 4
>>> [u'name', u'ftp_name', 'created_at', u'status_customer']

# OR just use this cursor function:

print(cursor.column_names)

>>> (u'name', u'ftp_name', 'created_at', u'status_customer')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

SHOW COLUMNS FROM your-database-name.your-table-name